# text_size cannot be resolved in R.dimen?

Tags: android

I don't understand why my value `text_size` is not resolved ?

Here my code:

```
this.menuTextePaint.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size));
```

`dimens.xml` is in value directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen
        name="text_size"
        >8sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

And i have the message : `text_size cannot be resolved or is not a field`

Thank you very much for you help !

Comment: check your imports!!! be sure it's 'import com.example.yourpakagename.R;' and not 'import android.R;'

Comment: Try `Clean` and `Build`. If still problem persist, can you tell where have you place the `dimes.xml` file?

Comment: Thanks for your answers
1-com.example.mypackage.R; is not resloved too... But when i write R in my project, it appears "dimen" but not text_size ...
2 - i try to clean and build and nothing better ... i put dimens.xml in res->values

Comment: okay. Cool. And I'm assuming you are using the write `context` ?

Comment: Yes, R seems to be known but not the "text_size" value. When i write R. it doesn't appears...

Comment: it's ok. I put import net.mypackage.R and not android.R and it works ! Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

For the future users, it was an **importing** problem.

`text_size` exist in project resources and not in Android resources, so importing  `net.mypackage.R;` instead of  `android.R;` fix the error.